# How can we make this maven POM.xml more professional?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, maven, pom.xml

It is the first time we're trying maven with google app engine, google web toolkit (platform, gwtp) and eclipse. We put this up with code we found here and there. We wonder if this POM file can be improved and how, since we're pretty sure it can be improved, particularly, the build section:

```
<!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.feeling</groupId>
<artifactId>order2012</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>com.feeling.order2012</name>
<properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwt.version>2.4.0</gwt.version>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.6 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <gwtp.version>0.6</gwtp.version>
    <gae.version>1.6.0</gae.version>
    <gae.home>${user.home}/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/${gae.version}/appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}</gae.home>
    <persistence-api.version>1.0</persistence-api.version>
    <jsr107cache.version>1.1</jsr107cache.version>
    <gin.version>1.5.0</gin.version>
    <guice.version>3.0-rc3</guice.version>
    <aopalliance.version>1.0</aopalliance.version>
    <gwt-maven-plugin.version>2.4.0</gwt-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-gae-plugin.version>0.9.2</maven-gae-plugin.version>
    <maven-clean-plugin.version>2.3</maven-clean-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-deploy-plugin.version>2.5</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
    <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.8</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
    <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>2.7</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.5</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <slf4f.version>1.6.1</slf4f.version>
    <maven-source-plugin.version>2.1.2</maven-source-plugin.version>
    <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>2.6</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
    <localJarDirectory>/Users/healuser/Documents/myGAE10/lib</localJarDirectory>
</properties>
<dependencies>….</dependencies>
<repositories>….</repositories>
<build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>target/www/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Add source folders to test classpath in order to run gwt-tests as
        normal junit-tests <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
                <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>

                 ! - - Folder for generated testing stuff - - 
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>gwt.args</name>
                        <value>-out target/www</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>  -->
        <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/www</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Eclipse configuration -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-eclipse-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildCommand>
                        <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
                    </buildCommand>
                    <buildCommand>
                        <name>net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleBuilder</name>
                    </buildCommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.gaeNature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>net.sf.eclipsecs.core.CheckstyleNature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalConfig>
                    <file>
                        <name>.checkstyle</name>
                        <location>/checkstyle/eclipse-checkstyle.xml</location>
                    </file>
                </additionalConfig>
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <sourceInclude>*.ui.xml</sourceInclude>
                </sourceIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- GWT configuration -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <appEngineVersion>${gae.version}</appEngineVersion>
                <appEngineHome>${gae.home}</appEngineHome>
                <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                <style>
                    $ {
                        gwt.style
                    }
                </style>
                <hostedWebapp>target/www</hostedWebapp>
                <server>com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher</server>
                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                <runTarget>order2012.html</runTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>gwtcompile</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- AppEngine configuration -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-gae-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdkDir>${gae.home}</sdkDir>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-server-jar</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>remove-gwt-user-jar</id>
                    <phase>post-installation-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>gwt-user*.jar</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/order2012</directory>
                    </fileset>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
            only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[0.8.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Custom Properties are great but don't use them just because they exist.  Use them to eliminate redundancy and/or defer management to parent POMs.  Other than that, I don't see anything wrong per the scope of your question.

Comment: @Tom: True. Just get rid of all properties that are used once.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your config would be common to any gae-gwt-eclipse-maven project.  So you could create a project to standardise that configuration (say `gae-gwt-eclipse-base`, with `<packaging>pom</packaging>`) containing all that, then your real project would inherit from that POM and divest itself of all the boilerplate you've listed.  Indeed it might be completely empty aside from the identifiers and `<parent>` section, which would amount to declaring "This is a standard GAE-GWT-Eclipse project."

If you've only got one GAE-GWT-Eclipse project, it's hard to be sure what's common and what's specific, but I think it might be worth doing all the same.

Another improvement would be to put configuration into the `pluginManagement` section instead of `plugins`.

`pluginManagement` says, "If I should use these plugins, here's the configuration I'll want (unless I choose to override it). But I'm not saying I *will* use them."  Whereas the `plugins` section says, "I want you to execute these plugins when you build this project," and maybe also, "and use this configuration rather than anything you've inherited."